# iPhone video recording: "cameraCaptureMode 1 not available because mediaTypes does contain public.movie"

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I tried to record a video.
The message I got is from the following code on the device:

```c
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
[imagePickerController release];
```

Any ideas? I think it should be really easy to take a video. When I start the "Camera" app of the phone I have the choice between video and picture. Shouldn't it be available for my app also?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The problem was the way I was trying to set the mode to video mode.

Instead of using this:

```
imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
```

I changed it to this:

```
imagePickerController.mediaTypes =  
        [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
```

and it worked.

Comment: Thank's for this info. It did it for me after I imported the "MobileCoreServices"-Framework ;-)

Comment: what is the difference between `mediaTypes` and `cameraCaptureMode`?

Comment: Seemed to be an issue with the order of the statements. The following worked for me (after importing the MobileCoreServices framework).  `imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];  
    imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode=UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;`

Comment: how did you guys get the thumbnail of the video and the video?

Comment: `mediaTypes` controls the type of media (movies and images) available for selection. `cameraCaptureMode` determines which of the options (Video or Photo) is the default when the UIImagePickerController loads.

Comment: Best answer !! Thanks

Comment: Thanks, i use `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, (NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];` now my picker controller supports both photo and video.

Answer (score 11):

> For Swift 3.0, you have to add below line to support both photo and video

```
import MobileCoreServices

  imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String, kUTTypeImage as String]
```

Answer (score 7):

Add to above answers, as Micko mentioned, you need to add MobileCoreServices.framework in your project and ref it in your imagePickerController. 
For those who want to have a switch under the toolbar in your image shooting view, just set the mediaTypes delegate as follows:

```
imagePC.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
```

Now, you can have both still image taking and video taking, enjoy!!!

Answer (score 5):

**Xcode 9 - Swift 4.x**:

Take care about the order of these statements:

```
imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = .video
```

And you remember to add to `info.plist:`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

And if you are working with Swift, then you will have to add MobileCoreServices.framework as well as the following **Module** where you are trying to record the video!

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

Then overall your code will something like this

```
    var imag = UIImagePickerController()
    imag.delegate = self
    imag.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
    imag.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Rear //or Front
    imag.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie];
    self.presentViewController(imag, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: imag.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie] replace the line using imag.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String] in swift 3.0

Answer (score 1):

This method will opens the library of videos in my ipod 4.Not the video camera of my device.

Will someone tell me how to sort out from the problem ,I have tried the both ways described above.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
    imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
    [imagePickerController release];
```

and

```
imagePickerController.mediaTypes =  
        [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

enter code herePlease try this,this will opens the video camera

```
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
                {
                    UIImagePickerController *tmp_picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
                    tmp_picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;


                    tmp_picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];

                    tmp_picker.delegate=self;

                    [self presentModalViewController:tmp_picker animated:YES];
                    [tmp_picker release];
                    NSLog(@"button index is %i",buttonIndex);


                }
```